# java executor delay not working

Tags: java, timer, delay, runnable, executor

Ok so I have tried 3 different options of delayed executors for a void/runnable/timertask that I want to run after 5 seconds but all the codes I used didn't work. They would immediatly run the code.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);  
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(clearstage(), 10, 10, SECONDS);  
executor.shutdown();
```

the second code I tried:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();  
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(clearstage(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
executor.shutdown();
```

and with those I used a runnable task like this: public Runnable clearstage(){//code}
I have also tried the timertask:

```
reviveplayerover = clearstage();
Timer timer = new Timer();  
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(reviveplayerover, 5000);  
reviveplayer(namee, name);   
timer.cancel();
```

and then used the: `public TimerTask clearstage(){//code}`

Comment: Add what your `clearstage()` method is doing. Is it returning a `Runnable` that contains work you want it do inside of the `run()` method, or is it doing the work you want inside of `clearstage()`?

Comment: it is a function that doesn't return anything it only executes within the function.

Comment: `it is a function that doesn't return anything` - I don't really understand what you mean, then. In your question you have `public Runnable clearstage(){//code}` which says it should return a `Runnable`, which your `ExecutorService` would run. It would be helpful to see what your `clearstage()` is actually doing. It would be helpful to say what your actual problem as rather than what your solution is (the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your 'main()' method does not exit before the scheduled task have executed.

```
    // Example with a one-shot delay
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executor.schedule(clearstage(), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Done.");


    // And your clearstage() must be implemented like this:
    private static Runnable clearstage() {
      return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Code goes here...
        }
      };
    }
```

Comment: this isn't the problem I don't want it to execute multiple times only with a delay. if it wouldn't work like this it wouldn't even execute immediatly.

Comment: okay this works for me but other code won't get executed while it waits for clearstage to run. The reason why I don't use the easy thread.sleep(time) is because other code must still be runnable. and the code that gets executed between this time has an outside input on what to run.

Comment: Its just to add the awaitTermination call when you are ready with your other thread.

Comment: I alrdy had removed that and it worked. Thanks for your help I will mark as solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example using [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

```
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(clearstage(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The second argument is `initialDelay`. Here is the Javadoc

```
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable command,
                                        long initialDelay,
                                        long delay,
                                        TimeUnit unit)
...
initialDelay - the time to delay first execution
```

You are passing in `0` so the first scheduled `Runnable` will not delay. `ExecutorService.shutdown()` runs all tasks that were scheduled and then shuts down. Since you are also calling `shutdown()` immediately after, the task will not be scheduled and will not execute.

Another option if using `ScheduledExecutorService` is to schedule a task with a delay using the `public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit);` method. Since it is scheduled before calling `shutdown()`, it will always finish.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduledFuture = executor.schedule(clearstage(), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
executor.shutdown();
```

You can also wait for your scheduled future to be complete. It is unclear from the question exeactly what you are looking for.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = executor.schedule(clearstage(), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
scheduledFuture.get(); // Wait for completion
executor.shutdown()
```

Comment: still executes immediatly.

Comment: @jeroen I updated my answer, but it is still unclear what you are asking.